# Each time I go through a loop, how can I get the next item of a list to display

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm coding a program that is a game of hangman and have everything down except how to display the hangmen. I won't post my entire code here, just the essentials to answer the question. Each time the user guesses a wrong letter one of these guys is displayed. Every time they guess wrong, the next one in the list gets displayed. Here is the list of hangmen:

```
hangmen=[
'''____________________ 
       |  /
       | /
       |/
       |
       |
       |
   ____|________________''',

'''____________________     
       |  /     |
       | /     (_)
       |/     
       |      
       |       
       |      
   ____|________________''',

'''____________________     
      |  /     |
      | /     (_)
      |/       |
      |        | 
      |       
      |      
   ___|________________''',

'''____________________
      |  /     |
      | /     (_)
      |/      /|\
      |      / | \
      |
      |
   ___|________________''',

'''____________________
      |  /     |
      | /     (_)
      |/      /|\
      |      / | \
      |       / \
      |      /   \
   ___|________________''']
```

And here is my system so far for correct/incorrect letters, very very simplified

```
words=['cat', 'dog', 'mouse']
word=random.choice(words).lower()
attempts = 7
for i in attempts:

    guess=input("Guess a letter: ")
    if guess in word:
        print('Yup, that letter is in the word.')
    else:
        print('Incorrect.')
```

the else at the bottom is supposed to be where the hangmen get displayed. How can I display the next hangman each time the user guesses wrong? Also, since there are 7 attempts and only 5 hangmen, how can I keep displaying the last hangmen if, say, the user guesses all 7 attempts wrong, without it crashing?

Comment: `for i in range(attempts):`

Answer (score 2):

I'd use [iter()](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/iter)

```
words=['cat', 'dog', 'mouse']
word=random.choice(words).lower()
lasthangman = hangmen[len(hangmen)-1]
hangmen = iter(hangmen)
attempts = 7
for i in range(attempts):
    guess=input("Guess a letter: ")
    if guess in word:
        print('Yup, that letter is in the word.')
    else:
        try:
            print(next(hangmen))
        except StopIteration:
            print(lasthangman)
```

This will print the next hangman value in hangmen every time a letter is guessed incorrectly, but it will keep printing the last hangman if we run out of hangmen. Note that this is still incomplete: what happens if I guess all the letters correctly before the end of the `for` loop?

Comment: 1) for in range(attempst)  2)  try:   print(next(hangmen))  except StopIteration:               print("You are dead")

Answer (score 1):

You could keep a variable that is added one whenever the user misses a question, such as:

```
words=['cat', 'dog', 'mouse']
misses = 0
word=random.choice(words).lower()
attempts = 7
for i in range(attempts):
    guess=input("Guess a letter: ")
    if guess in word:
        print('Yup, that letter is in the word.')
    else:
        print('Incorrect.')
        misses += 1
     print(hangmen[misses])
```

This prints the item in the list that has the index of the variable misses

Comment: Once more with feeling: `for i in range(attempts):`. But additionally there is no point in decrementing `attempts` inside the loop: you cannot change the iteration that way. And if `misses` exceeds the length of `hangmen`, you'll be off in the weeds.